# go binaries parameter passing

Tags: go, parameters, stack, elf

I'm trying to understand parameter passing in go ELF binaries

```
mov    %rdi,0x8(%rsp)   <----- first parameter (?)
mov    %r8,0x10(%rsp)   <----- second
mov    %r9,0x18(%rsp)   <----- third
mov    %r10,0x20(%rsp)  <----- fourth
mov    %rcx,0x28(%rsp)  <----- fifth
sub    %edx,%ebx
movslq %ebx,%rcx
mov    %rcx,0x30(%rsp)  <----- sixth
callq  5aaba0 <math/big.nat.shl> <----- call to native golang func
```

It seems that parameters are passed on stack, but when I look at the function [here (line 681)](https://go.dev/src/math/big/nat.go):

```
// z = x << s
func (z nat) shl(x nat, s uint) nat { ... }
```

The number of parameter is just **2**, and in the ELF it looks like **6** (?)

Comment: Ask this type of question on the golang-nuts mailing list where you will receive a high quality answer. Don't forget to mention which compiler exactly you are asking about.

Comment: [Go 1.17 introduced register based function argument passing](https://go.dev/doc/go1.17#compiler) instead of the stack (which improves performance by like 5-10%).